# Error installing Ruby on Rails in Mavericks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, extconf.rb

I've tried multiple solutions offered on similar question posted here but nothing seems to work. I can't install Rails. Error message is below. Also, Wwen I try to install Xcode by using `xcode-select --install`, it give me an installation o network `cannot download due to network` Please advise. I'm very new to Ruby so any assistance would be greatly appreciated. Cheers.

```
nmacaule-mn1:~ nmacaule$ gem install rails --no-ri --no-rdoc
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/nmacaule/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20150209-56320-1m9byas.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
checking if the C compiler accepts -Wno-error=unused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future... no
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
-----

The file "/usr/include/iconv.h" is missing in your build environment,
which means you haven't installed Xcode Command Line Tools properly.

To install Command Line Tools, try running `xcode-select --install` on
terminal and follow the instructions.  If it fails, open Xcode.app,
select from the menu "Xcode" - "Open Developer Tool" - "More Developer
Tools" to open the developer site, download the installer for your OS
version and run it.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/Users/nmacaule/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.0/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/nmacaule/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.6.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/nmacaule/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13/2.2.0/nokogiri-1.6.6.2/gem_make.out
```

Comment: try with  homebrew http://brew.sh and then install apple-gcc42

Comment: Hi Deep. Thanks for your help. I believe I tried. Home brew is installed on my machine. nmacaule-mn1:~ nmacaule$ brew install wget
Warning: wget-1.16.1 already installed. Brew version is 0.9.5.  How do I install apple-gcc42? I tried brew install apple-gcc42 but it failed.  Again, I'm quite new at this so a detailed explanation would really help. Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Run this command:

```
xcode-select --install
```